# Read current URL or URL variable in joomla

Tags: php, url, joomla, joomla2.5, http-referer

I'm using joomla 2.5. I'm trying to read URL variable OR full URL in Joomla component customization.

I'm able to read URL like:

```
http://xyz/index.php?option=com_xyz&format=raw&tmpl=component&lang=en
```

But I would like to read URL which is on browser (**with alias**):

```
http://xyz/en/feedback?ID=123456&Email=abc@hotmail.com
```

`feedback` is a Joomla alias. I'm redirecting that URL with variable from another PHP script.

If I try:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  // not working in IE.

$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] //return com_xyz&format=raw&tmpl=component&lang=en

JRequest::getVar('Email'); // return NULL but works if try getVar('lang');
```

Is there any other solution or better way?

Comment: @felipsmartins didn't find more info there can you explain me. tried but same result didn't get variable values.

Comment: @felipsmartins :- doesn't make sense they are both different questions.

Comment: What you want to do, cause your question is not  clear.

Comment: Would like to read URl with alias and varibale

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following. Might be what you're looking for:

```
$url = JUri::current();
echo $url;
```

Using Javascript, you could use this:

```
document.location.href
```

Comment: :- got //xyz/index.php?option=com_xyz&format=raw&tmpl=component&lang=en But would like to get another one,